# loop over 2 arrays and match their values and output into a new single array in javascript

Tags: javascript, css, arrays

As the title suggests, I am trying to create a function that can build me a css animation.

I accept 3 parameters in the function:

- Name = what you will call the animation
- steps = the steps the animation should take (ie: ["0%","50%","100%"])
- stepProperties = the css properties to be added into the step

I want to then take those parameters and "match" them with one another (steps[0] and stepProperties[0] should go together, etc)

Then I want to push to conjoined and matched parameter into a new array called keyframeProperties, so for example:

```
 createAnimation("testAnimation", ["0%", "25%", "50%", "75%", "100%"], ["background: blue","background: red","background: yellow","background: purple","background: green"]);
```

I should expect that after the loop, keyframeProperties is now equal to:

```
keyframeProperties["0%{background: blue}","25%{background: red}","50%{background: yellow}","75%{background: purple}","100%{background: green}"]
```

Here is my current code:

```
var createAnimation =  function(name, steps, stepProperties) {
         //set up a new array which will hold our properties to insert into the animation
         var keyframeProperties = [];
         //loop over the steps and the step properties and push them into the keyframeProperties array in their right format
         for (var i = 0; i < steps.length; i++) {
             for (var j = 0; j < stepProperties.length; j++) {
                  keyframeProperties.push(steps[i] + "{" + stepProperties[j] + "}");
             }
        }
        var animation = '@keyframes ' + name + '{' + 
                                keyframeProperties +
                            '}';
         alert(animation);
}
```

I hope all that made sense!

--SD

Comment: Why declare the function as a variable instead of as a function? Of course there may be reasons, but out of context it seems the odd choice to make. In any case, to avoid potential syntax errors it's a good idea to end such a definition with a semicolon.

Comment: This is why: `<script>
  // Error
  functionOne();

  var functionOne = function() {
  };
</script>

<script>
  // No error
  functionTwo();

  function functionTwo() {
  }
</script>`

Comment: The difference is that functionOne is defined at run-time, whereas functionTwo is defined at parse-time for a script block.

Comment: Yes, that's a difference, but 1) it still doesn't explain why you're choosing this option (which doesn't mean there isn't a good reason, of course), and 2) I'm happy to see you've used a semicolon at the end in your comment :)

Comment: Answers: 1) Personal preference mostly, plus to me it makes more sense to define at run-time. 2) Did I? haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your were close to solve this issue on your own.
I just removed nested for loops and done some other small modifications, please ask if something is not clear.

```js
var createAnimation =  function(name, steps, stepProperties) {
        //set up a new array which will hold our properties to insert into the animation
        var keyframeProperties = [];
        //loop over the steps and the step properties and push them into the keyframeProperties array in their right format
        for (var i = 0; i < steps.length; i++) {
            
            keyframeProperties.push(steps[i] + "{" + stepProperties[i] + "}");
             
        }
        var animation = '@keyframes ' + name + '{' + keyframeProperties.toString().replace(/,/g, ' ') + '}';
        return animation;
}

var animationString = createAnimation("testAnimation", ["0%", "25%", "50%", "75%", "100%"], ["background: blue","background: red","background: yellow","background: purple","background: green"]);

document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = animationString;
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Note: there should not be commas in CSS animation declaration.

Comment: You are absolutely right but I was not solving that issue.

Comment: works perfectly! thank you so much, I spend over an hour trying to figure that out! (slow day eh?) haha

Answer (score 0):

Here is another take on the function and it has a slightly different API.  The routine takes three parameters: 1) animation name, 2) object of properties to be animated and properties' values, and 3) [optional] animation steps.

Examples:

A. One or more animated properties

`buildAnimation("blink", {"opacity": [0, 1]});`

`buildAnimation("fade", {"opacity": [1, 0.5, 0], "color": ["#aaa", "#ccc", "#eee"]});`

B. Specified steps (to be used for irregular animations)

`buildAnimation("blink", {"opacity": [1, 0, 1, 0]}, [0, 50, 75, 100]);`

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wxdpr9we/.

And a source code:

```
function arrayRange(from, to, steps) {
    var increment = (to - from) / (steps - 1);
    for(var i = 0, arr = []; i < steps; arr.push(Math.round(i * increment)), i++);
    return arr;
}

function buildAnimation(name, properties, steps) {
    var propertyNames = Object.keys(properties);
    var first = propertyNames[0];
    var length = properties[first].length;
    var animation = "";

    if(typeof steps !== "undefined" && (!Array.isArray(steps) || length !== steps.length)) {
        throw new Error("steps and values array lengths must be equal");
    } else if(typeof steps === "undefined") {
        steps = arrayRange(0, 100, length);
    }

    animation = "@keyframes " + name + "{";
    steps.forEach(function(step, stepIndex) {
        animation += step + "%{";

        propertyNames.forEach(function(property) {
            animation += property + ":" + properties[property][stepIndex] + ";";
        });

        animation += "}";
    });

    return animation += "}";
}
```